# Formula field that returns specified valued based on related field

Tags: formula

I'm trying to create a formula field on opportunity that returns the value 'engaged' if the opportunity owner = SDR or AE and the opportunity CreatedDate was less than 4 months ago, but if the CreatedDate is less than 4 months, the field returns 'engaging'.

I've tried this, but the date doesn't seem to be calculating correctly.

IF(
AND(
OR(
CONTAINS(TEXT(Owner.User_Type__c) ,“Account Executive”),
CONTAINS(TEXT(Owner.User_Type__c) ,“SDR”)),
DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) >= (Today() - 120)),
“Ramping”,“Ramped”)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use contains when we can be explicit Especially if User Type is a picklist, which is should be. Try this, I didn't test it out with the dates but the rest of it should work and at least get you in the right direction.

```
IF(
  NOW() >= ADDMONTHS(CreatedDate, -4) &&
  (
   ISPICKVAL(Owner.User_Type__c, 'Account Executive') ||
   ISPICKVAL(Owner.User_Type__c, 'SDR')
  ),
 'Engaged',
IF(
 NOW() <= ADDMONTHS(CreatedDate, -4),
 'Engaging',
 'ERROR'
 )
)
```